# Cassandra Failed to import from CSV

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, data-science

I'm running cassandra as a docker container and trying to import a CSV file into my table. I keep getting this error: `Failed to import 0 rows: IOError - Can't open '/Users/myFilePath/Desktop/data.csv' for reading: no matching file found,  given up after 1 attempts`

I do have `data.csv` file on my desktop.

This is what my table looks like:

```
create table mydata
(
Rank int primary key,
Title varchar,
Genre SET<text>,
Director varchar,
Actors SET<text>,
Year int,
Runtime_Minutes int,
Rating varchar,
Votes int,
Revenue_Millions varchar,
Metascore int
);
```

This is how I'm trying to import the file:
`COPY mydata (Rank, Title, Genre, Director, Actors, Year, Runtime_Minutes, Rating, Votes, Revenue_Millions, Metascore) FROM '/Users/myFilePath/Desktop/data.csv' WITH HEADER = 'true';`

Please kindly let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you so much and truly appreciate your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason is that Cassandra/cqlsh doesn't have access rights for files on your desktop - such access is disabled by default on the latest versions of MacOS.  Check Privacy settings in the Application settings.

I also recommend instead of using `COPY ... FROM`, use the [DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) tool - it's heavily optimized for data loading/unloading for both CSV & JSON formats, and is very flexible.

DataStax blog has a series of articles about DSBulk: [1](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/03/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading), [2](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading), [3](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-common-settings), [4](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-common-settings), [5](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/07/datastax-bulk-loader-counting), [6](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/12/datastax-bulk-loader-examples-loading-other-locations)